# How to write data continuously from UserForm to excel sheet vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add new data to excel sheet via UserForm but it's doesn't write continuously. just replace value of range E2 and its rows.

> Note:If data already exist then update its relevant columns or write
> new data to next empty row.

my code is below.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

    Dim FindValue As String, Rng As Range
    Dim iRow As Long, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("ITEM NAMES")
    iRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    FindValue = TextItemName
    If Trim(FindValue) <> "" Then
        With ws2.Range("E:E")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindValue, _
                            After:=.Cells(1), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Rng.Offset(0, 1) = TextHSNCode.Value
            Else
                ws2.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = TextItemName.Value
                ws2.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = TextHSNCode.Value
              
            End If

        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to include something to find the last used row and write your data to the next row. There are thousands of other questions that already have answers for how to do that. Search here or on google :)

Comment: You are writing to columns 5 and 6 but using the last row in column 2. Maybe change to `iRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: Thank you Mr.@CDP1802, You made my day. Problem solved